# Save record, calculate sum and send to control at the same time?

Tags: ms-access

I have this form in which the user puts in the total quantity of an item. To facilitate their counting I made a pop-up continuous form with a summing control in the footer that lets the user enter several units of quantities and save only one ( e.g: 10;10;10;5 - 35 to be entered in the main form)

I managed to get it to work using `Forms![MainFormName]![ControlName].Value = Forms![PopupFormName]![NameOfSummingControl].Value`. The issue is that the cursor has to be on an empty/new record line for the SumControl to be updated and I want to reduce the time needed to enter the information.
I made an event on a button that does `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` before the above line of code and it works if I press the button twice.
Pressing it only once doesn't change the field in the main form which leads me to believe that it takes more time to update the SumControl then to execute the two commands.

How do I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Recalc` on the summing form:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Recalc
    Forms![MainFormName].[ControlName] = Me.[NameOfSummingControl]
End Sub
```

I do not see any simple way around going to the next line. The After Update event is probably the best, so that means the next line.

Comment: Great. It works. This is my function I use for the button (and Keypress Enter): `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` ; `Forms![SummingForm].Recalc` ; `Forms![MainForm].[Field].Value = Forms![SummingForm].[Sumfield].Value` ; `DoCmd.Close` ;